# Pop up close button that does not appear if the user visits that page again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, local-storage

When the user selects the close button it closes the pop up, however if the user visits or refreshes this page the pop up appears again. Is there a way for the browsers to remember that this user has already closed this pop up message:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--====== Design by foolishdeveloper.com =====-->
  
  
    <title>Automatic Popup</title>
    <!--Google Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <style media="screen">
       *,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup{
    background-color: #808080;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    display: none; 
    text-align: center;
    overflow:auto;
}
.popup button{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
    margin:  0 0 0 auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
        background: #e04039;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup h2{
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.popup p{
    font-size: 1px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0px 0;
    line-height: 25px;
}

  
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>tretertertrt</h1>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos</p>






    <div class="popup">
        <button id="close">&times;</button>
        
        <p>
            <iframe width="100%" height="750" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CeWlh0rEE-8" title="One Data Point That Will Change How You Do B2B Marketing" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  <!--Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        2000 
    )
});

document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
    });
        
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user selects the **close button** it closes the pop up, however if the user visits or refreshes this page the pop up appears again. Is there a way for the browsers to remember that this user has already closed this pop up message. Do I need to use **localStorage** if so how do I use this?

Comment: So set localstorage value on close. On open check to see if exists.

Comment: At the moment I am getting a bit lost on where to add this localStorage code - can you help thanks :)

Comment: Do you know how to use local storage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage I the close event, you use setItem. Before you show it, you use getItem

Comment: thanks for the information, at present i don't really know how to use the local storage, still learning bits and pieces of web coding or unless there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("isPopupClosed"));
            if(localStorage.getItem("isPopupClosed") != "Y"){
              document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
            }  
        },
        2000 
    )
});

document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
  localStorage.setItem("isPopupClosed", "Y");
});
        
    
    </script>
```

This can help you please check.

Comment: Cool Phani thanks this works well! again thanks for time and help on this !

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  var popupcheck = getCookie('popupclosed');
  if (popupcheck != 1) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          setTimeout(
              function open(event) {
                  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
              },
              2000
          )
      });
  }
  document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
      setCookie('popupclosed', 1, 7);
  });
  function setCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires = "";
      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
      }
      document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
  }
  function getCookie(name) {
      var nameEQ = name + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Shozab for the information and code, the above tickets works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Dear in very simple terms, the process flow is like this.

First the code goes to `window.addEventListener("load", function () {});` which calls  `setTimeout(checkPopup, popupDelay);` to  call `checkPopup()` function after `popupDelay` ms which is `2000` in your case

Then in `checkPopup` function we call `getPopupStatus()` to see if the popup has been clicked before or not. By default the if statement is false unless we put value true in the local storage

In the case the we have not clicked on the popup close button before we call  `showPopup()` which shows the popup and saves the value for close button clicked at the end by calling `savePopupStatus(status)`

In the function `savePopupStatus(status)` we have the local storage code which saves the status with this statement `window.localStorage.setItem(popupDBKey, status);` where `popupDBKey` is a name we use to refer to value of close button clicked. in this case i named it `popupstatus` and `status` is the value we store if the close button is clicked. In this case I stored `true`

In the function `getPopupStatus()` the local storage code to return the value stored for the clicked close button is this `window.localStorage.getItem(popupDBKey);` where `popupDBKey` is the name of the value which is `popupstatus`

> Note the example below will not work here since this is sandbox

You can read more about local storage [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/)

```js
var popupDelay = 2000;
var popup;
var popupCloseButton;
var popupDBKey = "popupstatus";

function checkPopup() {
  if (!getPopupStatus()) {
    showPopup();
  }
}

function showPopup() {
  popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.classList.add("show");
  savePopupStatus(true);
}

function hidePopup() {
  popup.classList.remove("show");
}

function savePopupStatus(status) {
  window.localStorage.setItem(popupDBKey, status);
}

function getPopupStatus() {
  return window.localStorage.getItem(popupDBKey);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  setTimeout(checkPopup, popupDelay);
  popupCloseButton = document
    .getElementById("close")
    .addEventListener("click", hidePopup);
});
```

```css
#popup {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  display: none;
}

#popup.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita d
</p>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="popup">
    <button id="close">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andam for the information and code elements, ill have a read and play with - thanks again !